# Changing the display in Combo Box based on choosing a different combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two `combox` in `datagrid`. One combo is main category and other combo is sub category.
i wnat that When I choose main category then in the combo sub category I see only the sub of main category that I have chosen.

How can i do it?

```
public partial class Form4 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEV6-PC; Initial 
    Catalog=Tak_Net;Integrated Security=True;");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = loadData().Tables[0];
        addCombo();
        addCombo2();

    }
    private DataSet loadData()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

        //SELECT STMTS

        string Final = "SELECT Counter,DATE,V_BizName,Cost,PaymentCost,Notes 
        FROM dbo.Final_Cat_Global ";
        string P_Cat = "SELECT distinct Cat FROM dbo.P_Cat";
        string P_SubCat = "SELECT  SubCat FROM dbo.P_Cat where 
        isnull(SubCat,'')<>''";

        //Final TABLE

        cmd = new SqlCommand(Final, con);
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Final");

        //P_Cat TABLE
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = P_Cat;
        adapter.Fill(ds, "P_Cat");

        //P_SubCat TABLE
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = P_SubCat;
        adapter.Fill(ds, "P_SubCat");

        dt = ds.Tables[1];
        dt1 = ds.Tables[2];

        return ds;

    }

    //COMBO COLUMN
    public void addCombo()
    {
        //ADD COLUMNS
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.HeaderText = "P_Cat";
        combo.Name = "combo";

        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();

        //FILL ARRAYLIST FROM DATATABLE
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row.Add(dr["Cat"].ToString());
        }
        //ADD TO COMBO
        combo.Items.AddRange(row.ToArray());

        //ADD THE COMBO TO DATAGRIDVIEW
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);

    }

    //COMBO COLUMN
    public void addCombo2()
    {
        //ADD COLUMNS
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.HeaderText = "P_SubCat";
        combo.Name = "combo1";

        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();

        //FILL ARRAYLIST FROM DATATABLE
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
            row.Add(dr["SubCat"].ToString());

        }
        //ADD TO COMBO
        combo.Items.AddRange(row.ToArray());

        //ADD THE COMBO TO DATAGRIDVIEW
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);

    }

}
```

i try to catch selected item on main cat combo but i don't success..
can someone help me with this?

Comment: is it Winform application?

Comment: @Ravi *using System.Windows.Forms;*

Comment: Use an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check when the first combo box was selected and in that event, feed the source of the second one.

Comment: This comment is out of topic, but I **strongly** advise you to avoid such aweful naming. Don't edit your application for 3 monthes, and then, I'm curious to see your face when you'll wonder what `Form4`, `dataGridView1` or `combo` are referring to.

Comment: @Cid i can you help how to do this? i try and not success..

Comment: *I try and not success* I don't see the event code. This is like *I had an error message. What was it? I don't know, I clicked on ok*

Comment: what the syntax to find selected and feed the source of the second?